# How I create MSBuild compile target

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to define my own compile target similar to ClCompile or ResourceCompile targets.

How I do it ?
I tried the following but 'Compile' button doesn't appear in VisualStudio context menu for this file.

```
  <Target Name="MyCompile">
    <Exec Command="test"/>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyCompile Include="testfile"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi, reduced some content of the misunderstanding of this issue. And if you have any update with the work around please feel free to share here.

Answer (score 0):

Correct behavior. You can't just add a custom UI extension (Right click menu and build support) into the visual studio UI just by defining your own custom ItemGroups. If you want visual studio's help to compile standard code files (i.e. *.cs, *.cpp etc...) then you must use CLCompile.

Answer (score 0):

> But 'Compile' button doesn't appear in VisualStudio context menu. I want to define my own compile target similar to ClCompile or ResourceCompile targets.

A compile button(for C++ project) will be enabled for those files which included in Items defined by VS like ClCompile or ResourceCompile.

To get a custom target(Not sure,but i think it's more complex than a single target) working as ClCompile. It could be a quite complex thing.For a C++ project, I think the compile option is not only about a compile target or an Item.

I commented some xxx.targets and xxx.props, and find even some files are included in ClCompile Itemgroup,the compile would be disabled, so I think the compile menu would check something else deep in the msbuild structure.

**Update:**

> How VS knows that it can display 'Compile' menu item for a.cpp ?

A compile options is something like below:

[image]

After my check, i find it has something to do with `Microsoft.Cpp.DesignTime.targets` which `contains targets that are only used by IDE and not the real build` and can be found in $(VCTargets) path. But I'm not sure about this point. For this, I think whether a compile menu is enabled or not, vs will check not only the ItemGroup, but also something pre-difined in xxx.targets.

And for your situation, after our chat, the `compile` menu in a C++ project is not really what you want since it's only for .vcxproj. May the [Code Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2015) can meet your needs.

Comment: I mean right click on the file, not on the project.
How VS knows that it can display 'Compile' menu item for a.cpp ?

Comment: @NN_ A meaning but complex question.Now I think I understand what you want to know. I will share my idea about it in update, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. in vcxproj there is CustomBuildTool target that you can use for files but I would like to have a generic solution.

Comment: @NN_ Yes, you can use a target in .vcxproj file to customize your build process. But it's two different things like having a MyCompile button when you right-click your file as johnson mentioned above. To achieve your goal, I think you need an extension to add a MyCompile option to solution explorer, then in it's execute mothed or something like click-event have some code to start  your custom compiler, but it's quite complex I think. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am searching for solution that doens't involve VS extension. Something that can be done purely with MSBuild.

Comment: With pure msbuild, we can edit the .proj file to do custom msbuild. But for the MyCompile Button(Something related to custom UI), I'm afraid there seems no valid way for this. If you have any update, you can share it here.

Comment: Do you know maybe how VS knows to show Compile menu item for cpp, idl,rc files? Or files with Custom build tool configured ? Is it hard coded by the name or there is undocumented feature ?

Comment: I think VS determine whether show Compile menu by recognizing the suffix name of the file. And it should be a hard coded way by design.

Comment: The file extension is not hardcoded. It is easy to test this. Renaming file.cpp to file.z still preserves 'Compile' menu item on the file. So it is related to ClCompile target.

Comment: Yes, but that's because there is something like "<ClCompile Include="file.z">" changed in the .proj file. What you want is a "MyCompile" menu item, an UI named by you, not designed in VS IDE, that's not a single thing just about pure msbuild.

Comment: It is not limited to ClCompile target. IDL file has the following:  <Midl Include="UniversalAddin.idl"> and VS knows that it should have 'Compile' menu item.

Comment: @NN_ Sorry for some misunderstanding. Maybe what you want is making some file included in your MyCompile can be compiled by the Compile menu which provided by VS. If so, I think we may need to move this to a chat cause it's complex I think. I will modify the answer cause it's too long and I have some misunderstanding in it. looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192067/discussion-between-nn-and-lance-li-msft).